# How To Fix VSCode: Exception has occurred: ReferenceError: closeDescriptionPopup is not defined

Tags: visual-studio-code

Not sure how this problem specifically occurred. I've been doing some googling trying to narrow down what exactly is going wrong as my project was fine a few days ago. When i attempt to debug my VSCODE project i'm presented with this error.

[image]

this is a picture of my launch.json file:

[image]

Also, this an error if it helps displayed in the debug console.

[image]

Things i've tried so far,

1. Rebooting the computer
2. Uninstalling and Reinstalling VSCODE as well as disabling extensions
3. Creating a new VSCODE Project to attempt to debug
4. Deleting the launch.json file and creating a new one

Comment: paste an minimal reproducible code of your JS file

Comment: Had exactly the same issue today. Interesting, I found if run the project in normal VS, it works, and then it works in VS Code again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending some time debugging I solved this problem by simply installing npm packages, I executed command `npm i`

Just make sure that your npm packages are all installed and none is failing.

Hopefully this helps you or someone with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

just delete the launch.json file and it will work again

Answer (score 0):

I've solve this problem.

Remove the launch.json file and do not replace it.

Just try to build with F5 button.

Answer (score 0):

1. Start Debugging from within VSCode
2. run `npm start` from a separate terminal and wait for the server to start
3. refresh the page in your browser

My intuition is that this would create 2 instances of the server binding to the same port and cause a bunch of problems. I'm not sure why, but in my case it worked as expected and let me debug with breakpoints normally.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same error, aparrently out of nowhere. I realized that I had enabled breakpoints for 'Caught Exceptions', and this error appears to be one of these 'Caught Exceptions'.

To resolve it, I simply disabled these breakpoints, and that solved the problem on my end.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

You don’t need to use the VS Code run button with Live Server. You just right-click the HTML file in explorer and use the menu option “Open with Live Server”.